# How do I attach to an app running inside the Windows Phone emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug an app running inside the windows phone 7 emulator, but I can't connect to it from visual studio - `Attach to Process` -> selecting `Windows Phone 7 Emulator` transport displays an error:

> "Unable to connect to 'Windows Phone 7 Emulator'. Not implemented"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to connect to an app that is already running on the emulator.

It sounds like you're trying to connect to the emulator directly yourself,rather than the app running in it. Which I don't think is what you want anyway.

It may help if you think of the emulator as a virtual machine. That's what it is. (near enough.)

If you want to debug an app in the emulator, you need to launch it through Visual Studio.

Comment: I need to connect to a running app as I've run the xap through a .NET postprocessor (similar to postsharp) and it's screwed it up somehow; I need to attach to it to see the exception being thrown, and I can't run it directly from visual studio as it's been changed from what was originally compiled...

Comment: Can the postprocessor not be integrated into the VS pipeline? Like PostSharp can. (Or could last time I looked at it.)  If not, can you not just add a global exception handler to capture the error and get access to the details that way?

Comment: I've tried integrating it, but there seems to be something about it that the emulator or deployment doesn't like (a very helpful 'Parameter is incorrect' message...

Comment: May be that the post-processor doesn't like WP7. I'm not sure what to suggest apart from stripping back to minimum code to reproduce and then reflecting on the pos-processor code to see if you can identify the problem that way.

Answer (score 11):

As a workaround:

- open the solution configuration manager
- next to build is a deploy column, uncheck your project
- press F5

This will launch the app that is already on the device without overwriting it (and deleting its storage).

Comment: Thanks for this work around! I kept trying to use "Attach to Process" without any luck.